# Property 'key' does not exist on type 'DatabaseSnapshotExists<Player>'

Tags: angular

I am creating a project with angular and when I use Angular Firebase to get some resources it appears:
Property 'key' does not exist on type 'DatabaseSnapshotExists'

This is my code:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FBEpj.png)

Comment: Do you have a property named 'key' in your DatabaseSnapshop<Player> interface ?

Answer (score 0):

You can right key like this

`changes.map(c => ({ $key: c.payload['key'], ...c.payload.val() }));`